# Samba Ldap problem

Tags: ldap, samba

When I connect samba server through smbclient the error was generate like

```
 smbclient //192.168.1.56/smbshare -U sakshi
Unknown parameter encountered: "ldap machine suffix ou"
Ignoring unknown parameter "ldap machine suffix ou"
Enter sakshi's password: 
Receiving SMB: Server stopped responding
session setup failed: Call timed out: server did not respond after 20000 milliseconds
```

Hi I have som problem in samba configuration my configuration is like this

my testparm output is :-

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Unknown parameter encountered: "ldap machine suffix ou"
Ignoring unknown parameter "ldap machine suffix ou"
Processing section "[smbshare]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
    workgroup = OPENLDAP
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    map to guest = Bad User
    passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://openldap.server
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    add machine script = sudo /usr/sbin/smbldap-userad -t 0 -w "%u"
    dns proxy = No
    ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=openldap,dc=server
    ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
    ldap idmap suffix = ou=idmap
    ldap passwd sync = yes
    ldap suffix = dc=openldap,dc=server
    ldap ssl = no
    ldap user suffix = ou=People
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

[smbshare]
    comment = for ldap user
    path = /test
    valid users = sakshi

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    printable = Yes
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

and my smbd output is

```
[2011/04/04 17:08:43,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 12 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:44,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 13 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:45,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 14 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:46,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 15 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:47,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 1 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:48,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 2 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:49,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 3 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:50,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 4 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:51,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 5 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:52,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 6 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:53,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 7 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:54,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 8 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:55,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 9 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:56,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 10 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:57,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 11 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:58,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 12 try!
[2011/04/04 17:08:59,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 13 try!
[2011/04/04 17:09:00,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 14 try!
[2011/04/04 17:09:01,  1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 15
```

### Update

I changed my machine suffix like this: `ldap machine suffix = ou=Computer` but I still have a problem.

I am on Ubuntu platform on one system I had configure samba+ldap and now I can access the samba share through the Microsoft side but I still get this error:

```
[2011/04/07 17:15:21, 1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175) Connection to LDAP server failed for the 6 try! [2011/04/07 17:15:22, 1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175) Connection to LDAP server failed for the 7 try!
[2011/04/07 17:15:23, 1] lib/smbldap.c:another_ldap_try(1175) Connection to LDAP server failed for the 8 try!
```

Comment: You are maybe missing the ´smbpasswd -w ldap_passwd´. That's why you have authentication issues.

Answer (score 1):

First thing will be that you have a line in your smb.conf that looks like this:

```
ldap machine suffix ou=machines
```

or something similar. It must look like this, with an additional `=` character:

```
ldap machine suffix = ou=machines
```

Then it appears that your LDAP server is either not running or not configured correctly, which is the main problem. Did you start it? And on what platform are you, with which samba version, what type of LDAP server etc.?